# Updating a photo each time my page refresh

Tags: javascript, html, ios

I have an HTML page 
With an image hosted online
I made it with some help from here to set a timer to refresh the image

But the problem is if I'm not connected to the internet the image disappears

What I want is

- save the image locally
- Update the local image each time the page refreshes

So if I'm not connected to the internet

My page uses the the last image it has when connected

And if I connect to the internet the page uses the server image

Answer (score 1):

What you are thinking of is [caching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_cache).
Caching is where the browser saves a web page or resources to disk in order to speed up loading times.

## You can now use [service workers](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/) to serve web apps offline

EDIT: NEW 2017 ANSWER